# javascript add and delete section of html dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add and delete sections of HTML on the click of Add or delete button. The first 3 times I click the add button it adds more sections as expected and deletes the section as well when delete is clicked. But the problem is when I delete any row after that the AddMore Rows function doesn't work and no more rows are added.

Here is the code for Adding more rows

```
var hasHsa3 = false;
var hasHsa4 = false;
var hasHsa5 = false;

function addMoreRows() {

    // console.log("A: "+hasHsa3 + " " + hasHsa4 + " " + hasHsa5);
    if(!hasHsa3 && !hasHsa4 && !hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 3;
        hasHsa3 = true;
    }
    else if(hasHsa3 && !hasHsa4 && !hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 4;
        hasHsa4 = true;
    }
    else if(hasHsa3 && hasHsa4 && !hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 5;
        hasHsa5 = true;
        console.log(hsaNum);
        $("#addMore_1").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else if(!hasHsa3 && hasHsa4 && hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 3;
        hasHsa3 = true;
    }
    else if(!hasHsa3 && hasHsa4 && !hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 3;
        hasHsa3 = true;
    }
    else if(!hasHsa3 && !hasHsa4 && hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 3;
        hasHsa3 = true;
    }
    else if(hasHsa3 && !hasHsa4 && hasHsa5)
    {
        hsaNum = 4;
        hasHsa4 = true;
    }
    else if(hasHsa3 && hasHsa4 && hasHsa5)
    {
      $("#addMore_1").attr("disabled", true);
        // document.getElementById("addMore_1").disabled = true;
        console.log("button is disabled");
    }

    console.log("B: "+hasHsa3 + " " + hasHsa4 + " " + hasHsa5 + "\n");

    hsaBlock ++;
    hsaIds.push(hsaNum);
```

Here is the function for deleting the rows once Delete button is clicked.

```
function removeRow(removeNum,hsaNum)
 {
    // Remove from array
    var index = hsaIds.indexOf(hsaNum);
    if (index > -1) {
        hsaIds.splice(index, 1);

        if(hsaNum == 3)
        {
            hasHsa3 = false;
        }
        else if(hsaNum == 4)
        {
            hasHsa4 = false;
        }
        else if(hsaNum == 5)
        {
            hasHsa5 = false;
        }
    }

    updateHSATable();

    $('.hsaBlock'+removeNum).remove();

};
```

Comment: Please add complete code, HTML, JS, and CSS

Comment: This appears to be way over complicated and the multiple global variables are not the best.. Please post the HTML associated as well as how you call these functions.  Also this example is currently broken - the first function is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your actual code so from what I understood I think you try to do something like below. For adding element I use `appendChild()` and for deleting element I used `removeChild()`. hope this helps.

```js
function add(){
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var len = document.querySelectorAll("ul li") 
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(len.length+1);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}

function delete1(){
    var len = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    if(len.length>0){
      len[0].parentElement.removeChild(len[len.length-1]);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="delete1()">Delete</button>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```